$u^*$ comapact implies $u$ compact proof verification
Suppose that $X, Y$ are Banach spaces and suppose that $u \in L(X, Y)$, with $u^*$  compact, where $u^*: Y^* \to X^*$, given by $u^*(\tau) = \tau \circ u$ is the adjoint of $u$. I am asked to prove that $u$ is compact, using the fact that $u^{**}$ is compact.
Attempt. Let $i: X \to X^{**}$ the canonical embedding, which is an isometry, and $j: Y \to Y^{**}$ likewise. Then, we have that, for $x \in X$ and $\tau \in Y^*$:
$$(u^{**} \circ i)(x)(\tau) = u^{**} (i(x))(\tau) = i(x)(u^*(\tau)) = i(x)(\tau \circ u) = (\tau \circ u)(x) =\\ = \tau(u(x))= j(u(x))\circ \tau = (j \circ u)(x)(\tau)$$
therefore $u^{**} \circ i = j \circ u$.
Now consider the unit ball $B_X$ of $X$. Since $i$ is an isometry, $i(B_X) \subset B_{X^{**}}$, and as $u^{**}$ compact, $(u^{**} \circ i)(B_X)$ totally bounded. By the above $j(u(B_X)) = (u^{**} \circ i)(B_X)$, so also totally bounded. Further, since $j$ is an isometry, we have that $u(B_X)$ must also be totally bounded, therefore $u$ compact.
